# Who illustrates the current Firefox website?

Tags: illustration, designers

Does anyone know who's behind the playful illustrations on the current Firefox website? For example:

From the [Firefox mobile page](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/):

[image: Firefox mobile illustration]

From the [Firefox download page](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/):

[image: Firefox download illustration]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Creative Director of Mozilla [here](http://www.intothefuzz.com/2010/11/06/creating-a-new-illustration-for-sumo/), the two companies responsible for the current design are [Delicious Design League](http://deliciousdesignleague.com/portfolio/?index=5) and [Royal Order](http://theroyalorder.com/?client_id=68).